# Deploying a VM under load balancer gives me an error in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-load-balancer, azure-vm

I have one VN and two subnets within it, I am creating a VM which has no public IP on Zone 1. I then created  a loadbalance and made a backend pool and put the backend-pool in the same VN as VM.

I now tries to associate backendpool with the VM. As I told my VM is in Zone1. When I tries to associated my VM to backendpool of loadbalancer I get below error

```
{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"BadRequest","message":"{\r\n \"error\": {\r\n \"code\": \"ComputeResourceZoneConstraintDoesNotMatchPublicIPAddressZoneConstraint\",\r\n \"message\": \"Compute resource /subscriptions/69c94256-2d95-43fa-8c2e-ac669cdb621d/resourceGroups/thermo-breast-cancer-rg/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/thermo-breast-cancer-devvm1 has a zone constraint 1 but the PublicIPAddress /subscriptions/69c94256-2d95-43fa-8c2e-ac669cdb621d/resourceGroups/thermo-breast-cancer-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/12.12.25.25 used by the compute resource via NetworkInterface or LoadBalancer has a different zone constraint Regional.\",\r\n \"details\": []\r\n }\r\n}"}]}
```

I can not figure out where I am doing mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a **Standard** load balancer instead of Basic SKU with same zone as your backend VM zone.

[image]

> To align and guarantee your frontend and backend with a single zone,
> only place virtual machines within the same zone into the
> corresponding backend pool.
>
> To address virtual machines across multiple zones, place virtual
> machines from multiple zones into the same backend pool.

Read [Standard Load Balancer and Availability Zones](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-standard-availability-zones) for more details.

Comment: Is it possibel to go with basic one?

Comment: It's impossible to use basic LB for a zonal VM.